# Coloring scatter plot in terms of an intensity in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

We would like to explain a continuous variable Y in terms of `X1,X2,X3,X4,X5` (continuous grades from 0/20 to 20/20).

When plotting `Y` vs. `X1`, I would like to color the points in terms of the means `(X1+X2+X3+X4+X5)/5` to see if the candidates that are bad in `X1` are globally bad.

So, `mean`, varying from 0 to 20, would be blood red and gradually going to bright green for the ones having (and also indicate this in a legend). How could one proceed this?

Here is how I usually draw my scatter plots:

```
scatter.smooth(x=data$X1, y=data$Y1, main="Y1 ~ X1", xlab="X1", ylab="Y1")
```

Even better would be that each point is colored in terms of its X1 value, and has a colored "ring" around it corresponding to the color of its mean.

Comment: welcome to stack. If you want someone to help you, please follow the advices here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa or  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You should provide an example of your data or a dummy example so the people can try and give you working code.

Comment: STHDA has a good guide on how to set up ggplot, and [here is a link to doing the continuous color scale you are describing](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no objection to ggplot, it'll make these things easy.

To shade by a continuous variable `aes(color=myvar)`, has the behavior you want straight out of the box.

Customize the colors with `+scale_color_gradient(low='red', high='green')`

To do the rings, draw two sets of points: first one with size 3 (or whatever) in the ring color, then dot the centers with a point of size 1.

Comment: Thank you. Really helpful. I still have a problem: myvar is the mean. But the worst mean that I have is around 6. I would like the color to start at 0, not 6 (and to finish at 20). How can I do that ?

Comment: I think you can just pass `limits=c(0,20)` as an argument to scale_color_gradient.

Comment: Do you know how to add a layer of points using ggplot in order use your idea for the rings ?

Comment: You would +geom_point() twice, and pass aes() in each to give them different colors. They are layered in the order you add them. If you edit your question to include a toy data set I can just show you, but I don't want to guess what your data looks like.